Google Earth Engine GEE - Add Landsat 8 images to existing code (working on S2) to retrieve lake surface area
I am completely new to GEE. Just need to retrieve lake surface area since 2012 at some locations.
I managed to 'mix and match' codes that i found online, and I came up with this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/9e938c085313a8a17d8d9d71f152dc08
This code does the job, but I need to extend my investigation back to 2012 (at least). Is there a way to add Landsat 8 to the timeseries, or even more sensors?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Considering posting it to GIS SE.

Give the following code a run: https://code.earthengine.google.com/564c5f68d18f899af23456cc5f10a9e9
Unlike Sentinel-2 imagery though there are gaps in the landsat images. To overcome that, have a look at this answer.
